# How to attach image with product and send image path to database(mongo) in NestJs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have two components, one is Book and second is Images. In image component I'm uploading images in diskspace. And in Book schema I have a property for images as well, because I want to upload the images for the book. I want to upload the image along with the book. But I don't have any idea how to attach the image with the property present in the Book schema, so when I upload a book, the image for that book will also be uploaded and saved as well in the database(Mongodb) being attached with the book. I'm providing files, if anybody need more files i.e controllers and services, I'll upload them as well. Thanks

**1st Compnent: BookSchema.ts. Here is the schema for book with Image(coverimage) property**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
@Schema()
export class Book {
  @Prop()
  bid: number;
  @Prop()
  name: string;
  @Prop()
  author: string;
  @Prop()
  price: number;
  @Prop()
  genres_name: string;
  @Prop()
  coverimage: string;
}

export const bookschema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Book);
export type bookdocument = Book & Document;
```

**2nd Component: images.controller.ts. Here I'm uploading all the images, and I want these images to attach with the property `coverimage:string of book schema`. So when I upload a book a selected image from my system will also be uploaded.**

```
import {
  Controller,
  Post,
  UploadedFile,
  UseInterceptors,
  Request,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import { extname } from 'path';
import { map, of, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { BooksService } from 'src/genres/books/books.service';
@ApiTags('Book Cover Images')
@Controller('images')
export class ImagesController {
  static a = './uploads/images';
  constructor(private readonly bookservice: BooksService) {}

  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: ImagesController.a,
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          const filename: string = Array(10)
            .fill(null)
            .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 16).toString(16))
            .join('');
          return cb(null, `${filename}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
        },
      }),
    }),
  )
  uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(file);
    return of({
      imageid: file.filename,
      imagepath: file.destination,
      originalname: file.originalname,
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is not recommended to upload files directly to database. instead upload images to sever and store the image path in database, and map(attach) that path with the product.SO the final function will be like this.

> First we have to create a `variable` in which we can store our image path.

```
@Controller('images')
export class ImagesController {
  static imageUrl: string;
  constructor(private readonly bookservice: BooksService) {}

  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './assets/',
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          const filename: string = Array(10)
            .fill(null)
            .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 16).toString(16))
            .join('');
          return cb(null, `${filename}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
        },
      }),
    }),
  )
  uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File, @Request() req) {
    console.log(file);
    return this.imageUrl(file);
  }

  private imageUrl(file: Express.Multer.File) {
    ImagesController.imageUrl = `./assets/${file.filename}`;
    return ImagesController.imageUrl;
  }
}
```

> Second we will store that `imageurl` into over `coverimage` property.

```
addbooks(book: Book): Observable<Book> {
    book.coverimage = ImagesController.imageUrl;
    return from(this.book_model.create(book));
  }
```